# android upd broadcast slow reception

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, datagram

I have manage to write a async class that send a picture over broadcast and wait for clients inverse ack and then send the packages that were not received...
The issue I am facing is that for sending 1mb picture it takes really long (1min aprox) to complete ussing only two phones connecting to each other via wifi. Here is my code (sorry for the long code)

SENDER CLASS

```
public class SenderBroadcastAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, String> {

Context context;
public SenderBroadcastAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(File... imagen) {
    Log.d("SENDER","INICIANDO EL SOCKET PARA ENVIAR");
    InetAddress group = null;
    try {
        group = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.255");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int port =1212;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DatagramSocket rsocket = null;
    try {
        rsocket = new DatagramSocket(1513);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rsocket.setSoTimeout(2000);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (File i:imagen) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream2);
        byte[] prebuf = stream2.toByteArray();
        mandar(prebuf, rsocket, socket, group, port);
    }
return "ok";
}


    public void mandar(byte[] prebuf,DatagramSocket rsocket,DatagramSocket socket,InetAddress group,int port) {
        int DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE = 50*1024;
        int cantidadpedazos = (int) Math.ceil(prebuf.length / (float) DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE);
        Log.d("Pedazos", Integer.toString(cantidadpedazos));

        //Loop peaces 
        for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadpedazos; i++) {
            enviar(i,socket,group,port,prebuf,DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE,cantidadpedazos);
        }


        ////FINAL DONE
        String message_to_send = "DONE";
        byte[] ultimo = message_to_send.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket ultimopaquete = new DatagramPacket(ultimo, ultimo.length, group, port);
           try {
               socket.send(ultimopaquete);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

        /*AFTER DONE WAIT FOR INVERSE ACK OF NUMERED PACKETS*/

        boolean mandarfaltan = false;
        boolean ack = false;
        int countertoend=0;
        boolean cancelcheck = false;
        while (!ack) {

            byte[] recibir = new byte[5];
            DatagramPacket pkgrecibir = new DatagramPacket(recibir, 0, recibir.length);
            Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...");

            try {
                rsocket.receive(pkgrecibir);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.d("timeout","TIMEOUT EXCEPTION");
                if (mandarfaltan) {
                    try {
                        socket.send(ultimopaquete);
                    } catch (IOException q) {
                        q.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (countertoend ==7)
                    {
                        Log.d("error","timeout error no response to done");
                        socket.close();
                        rsocket.close();
                        break;
                    }
                    cancelcheck = true;
                    countertoend++;

                } else {
                    Log.d("ACK", "TIMEOUT CANELING PASSING TO DONE");
                    socket.close();
                    rsocket.close();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mandarfaltan = true;
            if (!cancelcheck) {
                String faltast = new String(pkgrecibir.getData()).trim();
                Integer faltaint = Integer.parseInt(faltast); ////euivalent to for i
                enviar(faltaint, socket, group, port, prebuf, DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE, cantidadpedazos);
                if (new String(pkgrecibir.getData()).trim().contains("DONE")) {
                    Log.d("ACK", "Received" + " " + new String(pkgrecibir.getData()).trim());
                    ack = true;

                }
            }
            cancelcheck = false;
        }

    }







        public void enviar(int i,DatagramSocket socket,InetAddress group,int port,byte[] prebuf,int DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE,int cantidadpedazos){
       //for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadpedazos; i++) {

            ////EN cada interaccion del for clono el array con las ip q recibiran el paquete
            //ArrayList<String> finallist = (ArrayList<String>) tosend.clone();

            String final_str = null;
            String counter_str = Integer.toString(i);
            int len = counter_str.length();
            byte[] final_strbyte = new byte[5];
            Log.d("HEADER", counter_str + " TAMANO " + Integer.toString(len));

            switch (len) {
                case 1:
                    final_str = "0000" + Integer.toString(i);
                    final_strbyte = final_str.getBytes();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    final_str = "000" + counter_str;
                    final_strbyte = final_str.getBytes();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    final_str = "00" + counter_str;
                    final_strbyte = final_str.getBytes();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    final_str = "0" + counter_str;
                    final_strbyte = final_str.getBytes();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    final_str = counter_str;
                    final_strbyte = final_str.getBytes();
                    break;

            }


            byte[] slice, imagetosend;
            DatagramPacket packet;

            if (i == 1) {
                slice = Arrays.copyOfRange(prebuf, 0, i * DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE);
                imagetosend = new byte[slice.length + 5];
                for (int s = 0; s < 5; s++) {
                    imagetosend[s] = final_strbyte[s];
                }
                for (int s = 0; s < slice.length; s++) {
                    imagetosend[s + 5] = slice[s];
                }
                packet = new DatagramPacket(imagetosend, imagetosend.length, group, port);
                for (int s = 0; s < 1; s++) {
                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            } else if (i == cantidadpedazos) {
                slice = Arrays.copyOfRange(prebuf, (i - 1) * DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE, prebuf.length);
                imagetosend = new byte[slice.length + 5];
                for (int s = 0; s < 5; s++) {
                    imagetosend[s] = final_strbyte[s];
                }
                for (int s = 0; s < slice.length; s++) {
                    imagetosend[s + 5] = slice[s];
                }
                packet = new DatagramPacket(imagetosend, imagetosend.length, group, port);
                for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++) {
                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                slice = Arrays.copyOfRange(prebuf, ((i - 1) * DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE), i * DATAGRAM_MAX_SIZE);
                imagetosend = new byte[slice.length + 5];
                for (int s = 0; s < 5; s++) {
                    imagetosend[s] = final_strbyte[s];
                }
                for (int s = 0; s < slice.length; s++) {
                    imagetosend[s + 5] = slice[s];
                }
                packet = new DatagramPacket(imagetosend, imagetosend.length, group, port);

                for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++) {
                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

RECEIVE CLASS

```
public class ReceiverBroadcastAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer ,String > {
boolean running = true;
Context context;
//public int counter = 1;
public ReceiverBroadcastAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


    Log.d("CLASS","INSIDE_MULTICAST RECEIVER");


    ////receive socket
    int port =1212;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //////send socket
    int eport = 1513;
    InetAddress eip = null;
    try {
        eip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.1");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    DatagramSocket esocket = null;
    try {
        esocket = new DatagramSocket(eport);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //////end sockets 


    /////Array used for organize the received packages and log the received headers to send inverse ack 
    ArrayList<Integer> headers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<byte[]> contenido = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    for (int a=0;a<30000;a++)
    {
        contenido.add(null);
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream imagen = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int counter = 0;
    ////////end arrays 



    //////Start receive
    while(true)
    {


        byte[] message = new byte[60*1024];
        DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);


        try {
            socket.receive(recv_packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] order = new byte[5];
        Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...escuchando en el puerto " + recv_packet.getPort() );
        String rec_str;
        String rec_order;

        Log.d("PACKAGE LENGTH",Integer.toString(recv_packet.getLength()));


        if(recv_packet.getLength()>5) ////Packages that are minor to 5 are done packages
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[recv_packet.getLength()-5];
            System.arraycopy(recv_packet.getData(), 5, buff, 0, buff.length);
            System.arraycopy(recv_packet.getData(), 0, order, 0, 5);
            rec_str = new String(buff);
            rec_order = new String(order);
            Log.d("DATA", " " + counter + " " + rec_order);
            /////add int counter to array
            ///////process buff to add to contenido array whit headers as index
            if (process(headers,contenido,rec_str,imagen,buff,counter,Integer.parseInt(rec_order),esocket)){
                counter =Integer.parseInt(rec_order);}
            ////end buff processing
        }
        else  ////done package
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[recv_packet.getLength()];
            System.arraycopy(recv_packet.getData(), 0, buff, 0, buff.length);
            rec_str = new String(buff);
            counter=0;
            ///procesar paquetes done  o querys..
            if (process(headers,contenido,rec_str, imagen, buff, counter, 0,esocket)){
                //counter++;
            }
        }
        ////end while
    }
    ////end doInBackground
}






/*image processing bound to notification*/
public void procesar( ByteArrayOutputStream imagen) {
    Log.d("IMAGEN_PROCESSING", "INSIDE....");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(fullPath, "something" + timeStamp + ".png");
    try {
        File dir = new File(fullPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        file.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        Log.d("File created", file.getAbsolutePath());
        fOut.write(imagen.toByteArray());
        if(fOut!=null){fOut.close();}

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagen.toByteArray(),0,imagen.toByteArray().length);
    notification(context,bmp,file);

}
/*end image processing */



    /*INVERSE ACK*/
    public void inverseack(ArrayList<byte[]> contenido ,ArrayList<Integer> headers,DatagramSocket esocket){
    running = false;
    Set<Integer> noduplicate = new HashSet<>();
    noduplicate.addAll(headers);
    headers.clear();
    headers.addAll(noduplicate);
    Collections.sort(headers);
    ArrayList<Integer> faltante= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (headers.size()!=0)
    {
    for (int o=1 ; o<=headers.get(headers.size()-1);o++)
    {
        if(!headers.contains(o)) {
            faltante.add(o);
            Log.d("Falta"," "+o);
        }
    }

    if (faltante.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("PROCESAR","YA ESTA TODO, listo para procesar imagen");
        ByteArrayOutputStream finalbyte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for(byte[] w:contenido)
        {
            if (w!=null) {
                finalbyte.write(w, 0, w.length);
            }
            else break;
        }
        String message_to_send = "DONE";
        byte[] ultimo = message_to_send.getBytes();
        InetAddress group = null;
        try {
            group = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.1");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DatagramPacket ultimopaquete = new DatagramPacket(ultimo, ultimo.length, group, 1513);
        try {
            esocket.send(ultimopaquete);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        procesar(finalbyte);
        headers.clear();
        contenido.clear();
        /////imagen processing ready ... process
        Log.d("PROCESAR","YA ESTA TODO, listo para procesar imagen");
    }
    else {
        for (int enviar : faltante) {
            String faltantevalue = Integer.toString(enviar);
            byte[] enviarfaltante = new byte[faltantevalue.length()];
            enviarfaltante = faltantevalue.getBytes();
            InetAddress group = null;
            try {
                group = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.49.1"); //<-- Wifi direct group server ip address
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DatagramPacket ultimopaquete = new DatagramPacket(enviarfaltante, enviarfaltante.length, group, 1513);

            try {
                esocket.send(ultimopaquete);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
        faltante.clear();
        running=true;
        ///end for
    }///end else

    ////end inverseack
}

///////Process received packages 
public boolean process(ArrayList<Integer> headers,ArrayList<byte[]> contenido,String string,ByteArrayOutputStream total,byte[] buff,int counter,int rec,DatagramSocket esocket)
{
    Log.d("rec" + Integer.toString(rec),"counter " + Integer.toString(counter));
    if (string.contains("DONE")) {
        Log.d("INVERSEACK","SENDING INVERSE ACK");
        if (running){            inverseack(contenido,headers,esocket);}
        counter = 0;
        //return false;

    }

    else if (rec != counter) {

        contenido.set(rec-1,buff);
        headers.add(rec);
        Log.d("RECIBED", "NEW PACKAGE WILL BE SEND");
        return true;
    }
    else{return false;}
    return false;
}



///////////////NOTIFICATION
public void notification(Context context,Bitmap bpm, File imagen) {
    Intent pendingintent = new Intent();
    pendingintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pendingintent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(imagen),"image/*");
    PendingIntent intentpending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context, 0, pendingintent, 0);
    NotificationManager notification = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Photo!")
            .setContentText("Photo CLICK to see")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.photo)
            .setContentIntent(intentpending)
            .setLargeIcon(bpm)
            .setLights(-256, 100, 100)
            .build();
    notification.notify(0,noti);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //do whatever...
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... Progress)
{

}
}
```

I really appreciate if someone can check and let me know what may be causing that BIG delay on file reception. (it is udp it´s suppose to be quick)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I know that the large code is hard to read :( . Please if you dont have the tmie to read it just give me an advice to improve the speed of datagram socket....
I suspect that I am performing to much tasks on the async task but I dont know how to return a byte array from the asyn task to process the bytes spearatelly